# How do I fix the pnpm run create:shared error?

Tags: github, dependencies, repository, local, open-source

I can't get to the next step in setting up freeCodeCamp locally.

I'm stuck in error:

`TS18003: No inputs were found in config file '/home/reconfigure/freeCodeCamp/shared/tsconfig.json'. Specified 'include' paths were '["*.ts","curriculum/*.test.ts","tools/challenge-auditor/index.ts","tools/challenge-editor/**/*","tools/challenge-helper-scripts/**/*.ts","tools/scripts/**/*.ts"]' and 'exclude' paths were '[]'.`

`Found 1 error.`

How can I proceed?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.